# VBA Activechart.CopyPicture object defined error

Tags: excel, vba, vb6

Im having a problem while creating and copying a chart in vb6 using excel. I have these following code

```
Private Sub CreateChart(Optional ByVal ChartTitle As String _
                , Optional ByVal xAxis As Excel.Range _
                , Optional ByVal yAxis As Excel.Range _
                , Optional ByVal ColumnName As String _
                , Optional ByVal LegendPosition As XlLegendPosition = xlLegendPositionRight _
                , Optional ByVal rowIndex As Long = 2 _
                , Optional ByRef ChartType As String = xlLineMarkers _
                , Optional ByVal PlotAreaColorIndex As Long = 2 _
                , Optional ByVal isSetLegend As Boolean = False _
                , Optional ByVal isSetLegendStyle As Boolean = False _
                , Optional ByVal LegendStyleValue As Long = 1)

Const constChartLeft = 64
Const constChartHeight = 300
Const constChartWidth = 700

Dim xlChart As Excel.ChartObject
Dim seriesCount As Long
Dim ColorIndex As Long
Dim marrayhold() As Variant
Dim counter As Long

Dim j As Long


With mWorksheet
    .Rows(rowIndex).RowHeight = constChartHeight

    Set xlChart = .ChartObjects.Add(.Rows(rowIndex).Left, .Rows(rowIndex).Top, constChartWidth, constChartHeight)
End With

With xlChart.chart
    .ChartType = ChartType

    .SetSourceData Source:=yAxis, PlotBy:=xlRows
    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = xAxis
    .HasTitle = True

    .Legend.Position = LegendPosition
    .Legend.Font.Size = 7.3
    .Legend.Font.Bold = True
    .Legend.Border.LineStyle = xlNone
    .Legend.Border.ColorIndex = 1

    .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = ChartTitle
    .ChartTitle.Font.Bold = True

    .Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.Font.Size = 8 ' yAxis Labels
    .Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Font.Size = 8 ' xAxis Labels

    .PlotArea.Interior.ColorIndex = PlotAreaColorIndex
    .PlotArea.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
    .PlotArea.Interior.PatternColorIndex = 1
    .PlotArea.Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
    xlChart.Name = "Chart 1"
    Call Copy_Chart
End With
End Sub
```

There is a function for copying the chart and this is where the error occurs

```
Public Function Copy_Chart()
With mWorksheet
    .ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Size:=xlScreen, format:=xlPicture
    .Paste
    .ChartObjects("Chart 1").Delete
End With
End Function
```

in the line `ActiveChart.CopyPicture` I get an error message that said "application-defined or object-defined error" I tried researching but I cant seem to find a way to fix this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, you should avoid using the `Active*` objects.

change to

```
With mWorksheet
     .ChartObjects("Chart 1").Chart.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Size:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    .Paste
    .ChartObjects("Chart 1").Delete
End With
```

Note, the reason you got the error is probably because `mWorksheet` was not active

Comment: The error is because the `ChartObject.CopyPicture` method doesn't have a `Size` parameter, but the `Chart` object *does*.

Comment: Neither the OP nor this answer tries to do `ChartObject.CopyPicture`.  And the OPs code _does_ work if `mWorksheet` is active

Comment: Hmm, indeed. But using CopyPicture on the `ChartObject` avoids the need to activate the `Worksheet` in order to access the `Chart`.

Comment: @ThunderFrame I see no need to activate the worksheet in order to access the chart.  I've run the code I posted with a different worksheet active (and even add a chart with the same name to the other sheet) and it runs fine - using Excel 2013.  The only caveat is I'd add a parameter to the Paste to specify where to paste.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a reference to the ChartObject rather than activating and relying on the Active ChartObject.

On 2013, there isn't any need to activate the sheet, but be aware of accessing the Chart property - That will require activating the sheet. See [How do I reference charts with the same name, but on different worksheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38916459/how-do-i-reference-charts-with-the-same-name-but-on-different-worksheets/39424280#39424280)

Also, The CopyPicture method doesn't have an argument named `Size`, so you'll need to remove the `Size:=xlScreen`

```
Public Function Copy_Chart()
  Dim mWorksheet
  Set mWorksheet = Sheet1
  If Not mWorksheet Is Nothing Then
    With mWorksheet
      .Activate
      Dim cht As ChartObject
      Set cht = .ChartObjects("Chart 1")
      cht.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
      .Paste
      cht.Delete
    End With
  End If
End Function
```