# VBA: Telling two charts with the same name apart?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on a file that has gone through lots of hands. One of the charts I need is named "Dummy_1"; unfortunately, another chart has the same name. So `ws.ChartObjects("Dummy_1").Copy` gives me the wrong one.

Is there a way to differentiate between the two? Or in general, is there a way to target a chart other than by name? I know I can select it by index, but that's not really what I would call "targeted". Is there the possibility to pick the chart that is closest to a certain cell?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38916459/how-do-i-reference-charts-with-the-same-name-but-on-different-worksheets). I assume you have charts of the same name in different sheets, and activating the correct sheet seems necesary to access the correct chart. Or are your charts on the same sheet? In that case, maybe loop through these chartobjects and check their topleftcell?

Comment: @JvdV Same sheet. I could check for a header, that should work (do charts even have cells?), so thank you.

Comment: @JvdV if you programmatically create a chart, you can have the same name on a sheet (bad practice).  with that, you need to find a close target... Pythagorean theorem to find closest location to the target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine which chart is closest to a target location such that:

```
Dim ch As ChartObject, chr As Long, chc As Long, r As Long, c As Long, chin As Long, locr As Long, locc As Long
r = 24  'row 24, target
c = 11  'column k, target
For Each ch In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    chr = ch.TopLeftCell.Row
    chc = ch.TopLeftCell.Column
    If Sqr((r - chr) ^ 2 + (c - chc) ^ 2) < Sqr((r - locr) ^ 2 + (c - locc) ^ 2) Or locr = 0 Then
        locr = chr
        locc = chc
        chin = ch.Index
    End If
Next ch
Debug.Print chin
```

You can use the chart index (chin) to copy such that:

```
activesheets.chartobjects(chin).activate
activechart.parent.copy
```

Comment: I'll have to try this tomorrow, but this looks very promising. Thank you!